# Visual Studio 2019 "type or namespace 'System' could not be found"

Tags: android, visual-studio-2019, monogame

Not a single one of my references is working including 'system' and 'micrsosoft'. I am trying to make an android app using monogame through visual studio 2019 and I've tried repairing and reinstalling visual studio 2019 and neither has worked. My project name does have a space in it and I've attempted to change that to no success (perhaps I wasn't trying correctly). It was completely fine yesterday (08/01/2022, dd/mm/yy) and I do not believe I have done anything to cause this to happen. I am using C# if that helps.

Comment: Are you able to run the game?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem before, and I was very confused as well. I believe that the solution involves checking the packages installed for that project and making sure that the correct ones are installed. If the packages are outdated in comparison with the project, there seems to be incorrect ones installed which override and mess up the default reading of the system and Microsoft namespaces, making them unrecognizable. Make sure that you have the latest version of MonoGame, and that you make a project through one of those newest templates, which should set everything up properly. I have worked with MonoGame, and I remember this happening a couple of times. Like I said, just make sure everything is up-to-date, and that the project is made with those up-to-date tools. Lastly like you said, avoid anything that could cause further problems such as spaces between any of the platform projects, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The messages you are seeing are coming from an incomplete Intellisense loading.

**This condition should not effect the compilation or running of the game.** If the game does not run; There is something wrong in the framework or configuration files (Jump down to suggestions.)

The loading of SDK style projects, like MonoGame 3.8, is more intensive than the older .SLN files. Each of the NuGet packages is checked for updates, then loaded.  Only after all of the packages are updated, downloaded and loaded, does Intellisense start to load rules beyond the base C#.

Any sort of hold-up, like network delays, or issues such as low memory, slow hard-drive access or high processor utilization, can cause delays or timeouts in the Intellisense loading process.

To make things worse, the partially loaded Intellisense is taking up many of those same starved resources parsing and accumulating non-existent errors in any open tabs.

### Solutions:

Make sure you have enough RAM. On my system VS2019 takes around 3GB + the game.  Anything less than 8 GB is a non-starter.

Do not have anything else open when loading VS2019. Wait for it to finish loading before opening the project. VS restores the open tabs in a project, close them all, and wait until it is settled (there are tasks in the background so wait a few minutes), then restart VS.

Some virus scanners have been known to use large amounts of resources...(I am not going there, too many risks) ...

Or use a lighter editor like VS Code.

### Suggestions:

Develop and test as much of your game as possible using the Windows DX profile, since iteration times are exponentially faster. Then, when the logic is complete, create a new Android project and copy `Game1.cs` and all created files to the new project, changing the namespace in `Activity1.cs` (Android's equivalent to `Program.cs`) to match.